# Amazon EC2 -- Read Data From S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have many data files (let's call them `input_files`) that are stored in `Amazon S3`.

I would like to start about 15 independent `Amazon EC2` linux instances. These instances should load the `input_files` (that are stored in `S3`) and process them independently.

I'd like all the 15 independent `Amazon EC2` linux instances to write to **the same output file**.

Upon completion, this output file will be saved in `S3`.

Two questions:

**(1)** Is it possible for `Amazon EC2` linux instances to connect to `S3` and read data from it?

**(2)** How can I arrange that all the 15 independent `Amazon EC2` linux instances would write to the same output file? Can I have this file in `S3`, and all instances will write to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Yes. You can access S3 from anywhere on the internet using the S3 public API

(2) You are describing a database it seems. S3 is simply a file store, you don't write to files on S3 - you save files to S3.

Maybe you should look into some type of database instead.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to take a look at this :
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/role-usecase-ec2app.html

> Imagine that you are an administrator who manages your organization's AWS resources. Developers in your organization have
>   applications that run on Amazon EC2 instances. These applications
>   require access to other AWS resources—for example, making updates to
>   Amazon S3 buckets.
>
> Applications that run on an Amazon EC2 instance must sign their AWS
>   API requests with AWS credentials. One way to do this is for
>   developers to pass their AWS credentials to the Amazon EC2 instance,
>   allowing applications to use the credentials to sign requests.
>
> However, when AWS credentials are rotated, developers have to update
>   each Amazon EC2 instance that uses their credentials.

and to see how to do this with python:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/boto-users/RPoFskVw1gc

> The basic procedure is as follows:
>
> First, you have to create a JSON policy document that represents what
>   services and resources the IAM role should have access to.  for
>   example, this policy grants all S3 actions for the bucket "my_bucket".
>   You can use whatever policy is appropriate for your application.
>   BUCKET_POLICY = """{
>
> "Statement":[{
>
> ```
> "Effect":"Allow",
>
> "Action":["s3:*"],
>
> "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket"]}]}"""
> ```
>
> Next, you need to create an Instance Profile in IAM.
>
> > > > import boto
> > > >
> > > > c = boto.connect_iam()
> > > >
> > > > instance_profile = c.create_instance_profile('myinstanceprofile')
>
> Once you have the instance profile, you need to create the role, add
>   the role to the instance profile and associate the policy with the
>   role.
>
> > > > role = c.create_role('myrole')
> > > >
> > > > c.add_role_to_instance_profile('myinstanceprofile', 'myrole')
> > > >
> > > > c.put_role_policy('myrole', 'mypolicy', BUCKET_POLICY)
>
> Now, you can use that instance profile when you launch an instance:
>
> > > > ec2 = boto.connect_ec2()
> > > >         ec2.run_instances('ami-xxxxxxx', ..., instance_profile_name='myinstanceprofile')
>
> And the new instance should have the appropriate role and credentials
>   associated with it once it is launched.

there are same tutorials for Java, Ruby, ... Amazon website. you can refer to first url to see other tutorials.